# QT Drag and Drop Event Between List Widget and GraphicView

Tags: list, qt, events, drag

I have a `ListWidget` whose elements are all icons, and I have a `GraphicsView` on the other side. Here is the `ListWidget` event code:

```
void MainWindow::on_zemin_buton_clicked()
{
    ui->aksesuar_ornekleri->clear();
    ui->aksesuar_ornekleri->setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);
    ui->aksesuar_ornekleri->setIconSize(QSize(50,50));
    ui->aksesuar_ornekleri->setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust);
    ui->aksesuar_ornekleri->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("../1.jpg"),"11"));
    ui->aksesuar_ornekleri->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("../2.jpg"),"12"));
    ui->aksesuar_ornekleri->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("../3.jpg"),"13"));
}
```

When I click the push button, it clears the list and fills it with the right icons. (I have 4-5 more button click events like this.)

I just want to drag these icons and drop them into the GraphicsView. How can I do that? Should I set up the right design settings or write some drag-drop event code myself?

**Edit:** Now I realize that I want to do the exact thing with the Qt GUI toolbox. I want to add icons but don't want them to disappear from my list too.

Comment: Not much clear with your current implementation but you can have a look at this: https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/model-view-dnd.html

Comment: Thank you, but I've trie this and the GraphicsView doesnt support these classes.

Comment: On one side there is QListView or QListWidget and on the other is just a widget. You can still do drag and drop for all widgets: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html